# When I write number to an array, there is always one extra and repetitive last number

Tags: c++

For my homework, I need to open a file and read numbers form it. Then assigning each number to an array. However, the last number always added twice to the array.

the numbers in the file
8  1 9 1  7 2 10  8 2  6  2 7 3  10  10  10  8 1

the output looks like this
pin[0]=8 pin[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la6sl.png)=1......pin[16]=8 pin[17]=1 pin[18]=1

my code

```
void arrayFiller(int arrayP[])
{

    ifstream cleanout9;

    cleanout9.open("cleanlane9.txt");

    while(cleanout9.fail())
    {
        cout<< "fail to open file";
        exit(-1);
    }

    int i=0;

    while(! cleanout9.eof())//&&i<18) If I add this, I can control the output, do I have other methods?
    {
        int num;
        cleanout9>>num;
        arrayP[i]=num;
        cout<<"\npin["<<i<< "]"<<"="<<arrayP[i]<<"   ";
        i++;
    }

    cleanout9.close();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la6sl.png)

Comment: Thanks, I revised the cod.  while(cleanout9>>num)

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead.